# Can I use Overwhelming Strike to swap places with the target?

Tags: dnd-4e

I'm not extremely expert in the fourth edition, nor do I have constant access to the books, so I ask: overwhelming strike allows me to, on a hit, shift one square and then slide the target into the square I left, so, that being the case, could I swap places with the target?

Another way to ask that would be, can I simultaneously enter a square as an enemy leaves it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**No, movement does not happen simultaneously.**

Unfortunately, overwhelming strike is written such that:

> Hit: 1[W] + Wisdom modifier damage. You shift 1 square and slide the target 1 square into the space you occupied.

You initiate a shift. Because the shift does not state "even into the enemy's square" it follows the normal rules of a shift:

> SHIFT: MOVE ACTION Movement: Move 1 square.

which follows the normal rules of movement, save for the not-provoking elements.

Creatures occupy squares. Given that there are specific powers, (King's Castle, Rogue Encounter 1: Effect: Switch places with a willing adjacent ally.) which state "switch places", the general "slide 1" is not overridden by the "and slide enemy into the space you occupied."

Comment: My pleasure, mate. It's a bit fiddly.